# Adding hole to polygon using ArcGIS Online Web Mapping Application

Tags: arcgis-online, editing, donut-polygons

Is it possible to add a hole / donut / doughnut to a polygon when using an ArcGIS Online Web Mapping Application?

I have found the Edit widget but whilst is has a Cut, Reshape and Union function, it does not appear to allow cutting a hole in a polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out, very obvious in the end, but may as well keep the question in case it confuses someone else too.

With the Edit widget, use the Cut tool (Scissors) to cut a hole out.

[image]

Then to fill it with a new polygon use the add feature and ctrl to snap to the nodes